# Div "default margins" out of nowhere

Tags: css, html, margin

even after many lines i've written in css and html, the css-behaviour still manages to surprise me - in a bad way.

I was putting together a sample site for a friend to show him how he could build his layout,
but Firefox 3.0.5 and IE8 create margins between my #header, #content, and #footer-divs out of nowhere. If i switch in IE7 Mode, the margins disappear.

CSS:

```
html, body {
   background-color: #fff;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

#page {
   background-image: url('bg_gradiant.png');
   background-repeat: repeat-y;
   width: 950px; /* 770px + 2 * 90px; */
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding-left: 90px;
}

#header {
   width: 770px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#header #row1 {
   background-color: #9ab3ba;
   height: 50px;
}
#header #row2 {
   background-color: #517279;
   height: 50px;
}

#content {
   width: 770px;
   background-color: #d7e9ed;
}

#footer {
   background-color: #5eb6cc;
   width: 770px;
   height: 150px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
   <div id="header">
      <div id="row1"></div>
      <div id="row2"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="content">
      <p style="height: 600px">Beware of the Content</p>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can view this page here: https://codepen.io/lx-s/pen/eRrOpL

Browsing through the IE Developer Tools and Firebug showed me that they were no default-margin values set for these div's, but as one can see, they are there.
Hope you can give me a hint how to get rid of them - it's seriously driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the DIV but the P tag that has the margin set by default. I tested setting it to 0 and the space disappeared.

Comment: so p was the culprit.. - strange that the p-margin reaches out of it's parent div ....

Answer (score 8):

Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is bad practice as using `*` can cause performance problems. It would be better to use: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 3):

The margins are on the p tag in the #content div

Hope this helps you a little

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a reset css. You should do this on every Web page/site you develop. A good reset CSS will remove many of the default settings and make cross-browser look and feel much less painless.

There are several of these around such as [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or the [Yahoo UI Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen this before, I've added a padding-bottom:1px to the bottom of the containing DIV so that I can keep the margins on the Paragraphs

Hope that helps

Comment: alternatively try using the clearfix method on the div - Although there is nothing floated, it seems to contain the <p>s margin.